# Are there any electrically-conductive SLA resins?

Tags: resin, sla

I'm looking for an SLA resin that's electrically conductive. But, there don't seem to be any DIY or cheap formulations for electrically conductive resin.

If it were easy to do, we'd all be making circuits with electrically conductive resin. So I think that level of conductivity is probably not going to be available for a while. And I guess beyond the scope of this question. Likewise, a resin that was conductive enough for electroplating is also beyond the scope of this question.

A guy on YouTube mixed 5% graphite with resin and got 1.4 MΩ on his multimeter when the electrodes were placed about 2 cm apart. This is useful for electrostatic discharge but not much else. I'd like something more conductive than that.

I would like something similar to ProtoPasta conductive PLA, which has about 400-2000 Ω of resistance when you measure it 2 cm apart on a multimeter. It's not that good, but it's enough for a touch screen or button, for example. Someone on Reddit mentioned that people had formulated this before, but I can't find any evidence of that. At least, not with SLA resin - just that FDM stuff.

I even tried my hand at this a few months ago. I mixed some kind of generic resin with chopped carbon fibers, but it was kind of weird. The chopped fibers stuck out the edges of the final print, and were never really spread around that well. It was conductive but highly **ansiotropic**. It also looked horrible. The fibers clumped together in the uncured (and cured) resin, and it was not possible to keep them well-dispersed in the mixture throughout the print.

Does anyone have a good 1) cheap supplier or 2) cheap & simple DIY formulation for creating this kind of resin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are.

You will find them under the name "conductive UV resins and additives" and you can mix and match resins and additives to get desired properties. Of course the better conductivity, the worse printability most of the time.

From the [first manufacturer](https://www.3dresyns.com/pages/conductive-3dresyns-for-electronics) I was able to find (emphasis mine):

> Our innovative Conductive 3Dresyns have been designed to have excellent dispersibility and stability, without agglomeration issues, of pre and/ or post added metallic, inorganic and organic conductive and semiconductive materials for ultra fast additive **manufacturing of high-performance electronic devices such as OLEDs, OPVs, OTFTs, PCBs, etc** 3D printed at micron resolution (<20-30 microns) with SLA, DLP, LCD and Inkjet 3D printing.

I do not endorse this manufacturer or their products. I'm only using them as a proof of existence of the materials in question.

Comment: Well, I should have mentioned that I found this company, too, and that their additives & resins are a bit too expensive for me. They also require a special type of mixer, it seems. If I’m going to mix a graphene based additive into a resin with my own blender, I might as well be DIY-ing the whole process for slightly worse results, rather than starting with a $120 additive

Comment: @KMmmm yes, you probably should have. I answered question you asked. Not my fault it wasn't the question you meant to ask.

Comment: Well, it's not your fault, but it doesn't mean I have to accept your answer. The final line of my question asked for "Does anyone have a good 1) cheap supplier or 2) cheap & simple DIY formulation for creating this kind of resin?" I suppose cheap is subjective, but it seems a lot of commenters elsewhere agree that this 3dresyns resin is a bit expensive for the task. It's my responsibility to select the best answer for the question. If nobody else comes along with a better answer, I'll have to accept yours.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use conductive paint, it's under $20 usually for the basics.

Bareconductive is the only one I've used, worked well enough for my simple project. Other products might be better.